# Rails 4 How Do You Make 'date_select' Form Field Helper Required?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I've been trying to work this date_select form field helper in my Rails 4 app to be required but I have had no success.

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :birthday, "Your Date of Birth" %><br />
    <%= f.date_select :birthday, order: [:month, :day, :year], prompt: { day: 'Select day', month: 'Select month', year: 'Select year' }, start_year: Date.today.year - 18, end_year: Date.today.year - 100 %>
  </div>
```

I've done it successfully with text and password fields using (:required => true), for example:

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off", :required => true %>
  </div>
```

But I'm unable to translate the required parameter setting to the date_select form field. I have tried :required => true, and required: true as well, but no success. And I have been unable to find any answers concerning this topic on Google and StackOverflow.

I'd really like to work this out with a user providing their birthday data instead of setting a default date if the form is submitted with nil information.

Thank you very much for your time.

Reez

Comment: I've worked around similar problems with jQuery validation: http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: Thank you for the tip, Joe. Will reference it when building out my app.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The required is a html option so it's a separate hash from the other options. Use curly braces to surround the first hash so that the required is clearly in the second hash.

```
<%= f.date_select :birthday, {order: [:month, :day, :year], prompt: { day: 'Select day', month: 'Select month', year: 'Select year' }, start_year: Date.today.year - 18, end_year: Date.today.year - 100}, {required: true} %>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, Steve. I didn't have a clue that applying curly braces will be the ticket to success!

Comment: When you start putting key value pairs (e.g. key `order:` and value `[:month, :day, :year]` giving `order: [:month, :day, :year]`) It's assumed that that entry, and all following key/value entries, are all the same hash so the curly braces you'd use to define a hash aren't required.  If you need to pass in two hashes, though, then you need to be explicit about which key/values belong to which hash.

Comment: In my case, the {required: true} cannot wrapped in the curly bracket.

Comment: @V-SHY why not?

Comment: in my case, it can't accept the required as html options if wrapped in the curly bracket

Comment: Refer to this, http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder/date_select,
the source show us the options got objectify_options, but the html_options don't have

Comment: The curly brackets are necessary to separate the `options` from the `html_options` otherwise the parser can't distinguish between the two. Put the curly brackets around the two hashes and you'll be fine. Both hashes are passed in the source, but the `options` is run through the `objectify_options` method which isn't required for the `html_options`.  Examine this part of the source... `objectify_options(options), html_options`